# Bootstrap toggle doesn't work while resizing web

Tags: html, css

This is the code:

```
<nav xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security"  class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top container-fluid" id="navbar">
<div class="container px-4">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/main"> <img src="https://i.imgur.com/BKHVvT0.png" style="width: 100px; height: auto;"> </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
            <li  sec:authorize="isAnonymous()" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/login">Inicio sesión</a></li>
            <li  sec:authorize="isAnonymous()" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/register">Registro Cliente</a></li>
            <li  sec:authorize="isAnonymous()" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/registrohotel">Registro Hotel</a></li>

            <li sec:authorize="hasAuthority('CLIENTE')" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/historialReservaClienteVigentes">Tus reservas</a></li>
            <li sec:authorize="hasAuthority('CLIENTE')" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/perfilcliente">Perfil</a></li>
            <li sec:authorize="hasAuthority('CLIENTE')" class="nav-item"><a sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()" class="nav-link" th:href="@{/logout}"> <i class=" fas fa-door-open"></i></a></li>

            <li sec:authorize="hasAuthority('HOTEL')" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/admin">Administrador</a></li>
            <li sec:authorize="hasAuthority('HOTEL')" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/perfilhotel">Perfil</a></li>
            <li sec:authorize="hasAuthority('HOTEL')" class="nav-item"><a sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()" class="nav-link" th:href="@{/logout}"> <i class="   fas fa-door-open"></i></a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thing is that it does appear on screen, however when interacting it does nothing. The toggler bottom does appear, but when clicking, it doesn't make the nav items appear on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you add bootstrap cdns: both the script and the css. See the code snippet below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <nav xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security"  class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top container-fluid" id="navbar">
<div class="container px-4">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/main"> <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR1x67c2BlI-XYmmi_J78A5Lla6ztswREYwUF2wuHuF_UpOVlEjDeVgbMcU7idPQiJJLfE&usqp=CAU" style="width: 100px; height: auto;"> </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
            <li  sec:authorize="isAnonymous()" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/login">Inicio sesión</a></li>
            <li  sec:authorize="isAnonymous()" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/register">Registro Cliente</a></li>
            <li  sec:authorize="isAnonymous()" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/registrohotel">Registro Hotel</a></li>

            <li sec:authorize="hasAuthority('CLIENTE')" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/historialReservaClienteVigentes">Tus reservas</a></li>
            <li sec:authorize="hasAuthority('CLIENTE')" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/perfilcliente">Perfil</a></li>
            <li sec:authorize="hasAuthority('CLIENTE')" class="nav-item"><a sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()" class="nav-link" th:href="@{/logout}"> <i class=" fas fa-door-open"></i></a></li>

            <li sec:authorize="hasAuthority('HOTEL')" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/admin">Administrador</a></li>
            <li sec:authorize="hasAuthority('HOTEL')" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/perfilhotel">Perfil</a></li>
            <li sec:authorize="hasAuthority('HOTEL')" class="nav-item"><a sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()" class="nav-link" th:href="@{/logout}"> <i class="   fas fa-door-open"></i></a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```